# Formula to compute the number of MACs in a Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I couldn't find the right formula to compute the number of MACs in one Convolutional layer in a CNN.
I tried this formula from Quora

```
[((H-K+S) /S) *((W-L+S)/S)) *C*M*N]
```

Where :
H*W size of input feature map;
K*L size of filter
S stride
C channels of the input 
M Output feature map
N number of input feature map

I took an example :
1 input image 5x5x1
1 filter 3x3x1
Then I did a naïve calculation, I obtained 81 MACs. 
But when I used the above mentioned formula ai obtained 9.

I think that there is something that I didn't understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what exactly is a MAC?

Comment: A MAC is a multiply and accumulate operation since we're are taking about convolutions in CNN

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say you have these parameters:
K is you kernel width and height
C_in is number of input channels
C_out is number of output channels
H_out and W_out height and width of the output matrix respectively

Then, you need `(K^2) * C_in` MAC operations to compute each output feature map
and you will have `H_out * W_out * C_out` of these output feature maps.
Then total MACs would be:

```
(K^2) * C_in * H_out * W_out * C_out
```